# Magento Product pag - displaying related products that are out of stock

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento, product

I'm not too experienced in PHP but my goal here is to have related product swatches not display on the page if they are out of stock.(highlighted in screenshot)

[Related product swatches are highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QewL.png)

Here is the PHP code:

```
    <ol class="mini-products-list" id="block-related">
    <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
        <li class="item">
            <?php if(!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox related-checkbox" id="related-checkbox<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" name="related_products[]" value="<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" />
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="product">
                <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail')->resize(50) ?>" width="50" height="50" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" /></a>
                <div class="product-details">
                    <p class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a></p>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-related') ?>
                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_item) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </ol>
```

And here is the related jQuery/JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$$('.related-checkbox').each(function(elem){
    Event.observe(elem, 'click', addRelatedToProduct)
});

var relatedProductsCheckFlag = false;
function selectAllRelated(txt){
    if (relatedProductsCheckFlag == false) {
        $$('.related-checkbox').each(function(elem){
            elem.checked = true;
        });
        relatedProductsCheckFlag = true;
        txt.innerHTML="<?php echo $this->__('unselect all') ?>";
    } else {
        $$('.related-checkbox').each(function(elem){
            elem.checked = false;
        });
        relatedProductsCheckFlag = false;
        txt.innerHTML="<?php echo $this->__('select all') ?>";
    }
    addRelatedToProduct();
}

function addRelatedToProduct(){
    var checkboxes = $$('.related-checkbox');
    var values = [];
    for(var i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++){
        if(checkboxes[i].checked) values.push(checkboxes[i].value);
    }
    if($('related-products-field')){
        $('related-products-field').value = values.join(',');
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you have the option **Display out of stock products** set to **No**? *(System -> Configuration -> Inventory)*

You can also try to add `$_item->isAvailable()` to if statement.

Comment: Adding the $_item->isAvailable() to if statement worked PERFECT, out of stock products will not display as a related product swatch! :D.  To answer your question "Display out of stock Products" is set to "no" which is what we want, so that out of stock product pages are view able to customers who might share the page link or google the product but don't show up on category pages.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm looking for the same type of functionality for "related product colors" checkout this link to my question-> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38316719/magento-related-product-color-swatches

Answer (score 0):

**The Solution I ended up going with:**  adding $_item->isAvailable() to if statement gives the desired effect of related products that are out of stock will not display as a related product swatch on the product page.